# How to call one table multiple times in active report

Tags: c#, activereports

I have created table using active report which contains few columns.
Now I want to call that table multiple times.
eg. suppose if there are 3 buildings then that table should called 3 times.
    if there are 4 buildings then table should called 4 times.

I have to filled info in table according to each building.
Is it possible in active reports?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using ActiveReports.  Yes, this is possible, but we need more information about your report and your data structure to recommend a solution.   Please contact our support team at www.grapecity.com and include as much detail about your report design and the datasource and the team will be able to help you.

If I understood your case correctly, you can either group the data by Building and the group header would contain Building information and the detail would have building details.   Or you can place a List bound to Building and within the List you can have a Table for the Building details.   Again, not exactly sure, it depends on your layout and data.

Also, feel free to reach to our [forums](https://www.grapecity.com/forums) or [submit a ticket](https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact) if you would like assistance from the GrapeCity Support team.